# PHP Openid selector try_auth file

Tags: php, openid

I am trying to implement openid selector into my website, I wonder what is the try_auth file that I need for my openid selector to work?

All I want user to login into my website is using only their google account, so could anyone help me out? I have been doing alot of research and I didn't find a successful way of doing so. I am using PHP for my back end development.

Perhaps if someone could help explain how everything works that will be great, as well I didn't plan to use DB to store any user login. I know I have to have a session variable to check in every page whether user have login or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openid-selector is just a nice front-end for choosing which OpenID provider to use for signing in.
You also need a library that does the according back-end stuff. In your case this missing file is part of php-openid: https://github.com/openid/php-openid